# Simple script that computes a solution of linear ODEs giving wrong result

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

this a question that envolves both programming and mathematics. So, I'm trying to write a code that computes the general solution of a system of linear ODEs described by [image: system] . The mathematical formula it's shown above:[image: general solution]

where the greek symbol \PHI that appers in the equation is the `expm(A*t)`

```
 clear all

 A=[-2]; %system matrix

 t0=1; %initial time of simulation

 tf=2; %final time of simulation

 syms t x_0 

 x0=x_0;

 hom=expm(A*t); %hom means "homogeneous solution"

 hom_initialcond=hom*x0;%this is the homogeneous solution multiplied by the initial conditon

 invhom=inv(hom); %this is the inverse of the greek letter at which, multiplied by the input of the system, composes the integrand of the integral

 g=5*cos(2*t); %system input

 integrand=invhom*g; %computation of the integrand

 integral=int(integrand,t0,t); %computation of the definite integral from t0 to t, as shown by the math formula

 partsol=hom*integral; %this is the particular solution

 gen_sol=partsol+hom_initialcond %this is the general solution

 x_0=1; %this is the initial condition

 t=linspace(t0,tf); %vector of time from t0 to tf

 y=double(subs(gen_sol)); %here I am evaluating my symbolic expression

 plot(t,y)
```

The problem is that my plot of the ODE's solution it's not looking well, as you can see:
[image: plot]

The solution it's wrong because the curve shown in the graph doesnt start at the initial value equals `1`. But the shape it's very similar from the plot gave by the MATLAB ODE solver:
[image]

**However, if I set `t0=0` then the plot gave by my code and by MATLAB solver it's exacly equal to each other**. So, my code it's fine for `t0=0` but with any other values my code goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general solution in terms of fundamental matrices is

[image: Equation giving the solution of an ODE system with an arbitrary initial condition vector]

or more often seen as

[image: Equation giving the solution of an ODE system with an initial condition vector for linear, constant coefficient problems]

But since the initial time is often taken to be zero, the inverse of the fundamental matrix is often omitted since it is the identity for linear, constant coefficient problems at zero (i.e., `expm(zeros(n)) == eye(n)`) and the c vector is equivalent to the initial condition vector.

Swapping some of the lines around near your symbolic declaration to this

```
 syms t x_0 c_0
 hom             = expm(A*t)                ;
 invhom          = inv(hom)                 ;
 invhom_0        = subs(invhom,t,sym(t0))   ;
 c_0             = invhom_0 * x_0           ;
 hom_initialcond = hom    * c_0             ;
```

should provide the correct solution for non-zero initial time.

Comment: you forgot to evaluate invhom at t0 in the line `c_0=invhom*x_0`